# Font looks weird in Solution Explorer in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

[image]

When i create a new folder in Solution Explorer the font is little bit different from the default one like the image above. I am also using ReSharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like "SBC case" or "DBC case". Maybe your input method has some problem. Try "Ctrl+Space" or "Ctrl + Shift".

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font and colors from visual studio itself, below are the steps:

1. Go to tools in menu.
2. Select options
3. Expand Environment section
4. Select Fonts and colors option

there you can change the font and color of the font.

Attached is the screen.

Hope this will help!!

Cheers!!